# How to use feature to evaluate custom TensorFlow metric that is not used to train model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am training a model that does sequence prediction. For example, given the previous 10 words someone has written, I am training an LSTM to predict the next word they will write. I have a model that is sometimes working, and so I want to create a metric that tracks the model's ability to predict the next word by part-of-speech tag, (i.e. one metric for the loss when predicting verbs, a separate metric for the loss when predicting nouns, and then one last metric for the loss when predicting everything other part-of-speech). So, the data I have looks something like this:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------| 
| X                                                        | Y        | part-of-speech |
|==========================================================|==========|================|  
| When the sunlight strikes raindrops in the air, they act | as       | preposition    |
|----------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------| 
| the sunlight strikes raindrops in the air, they act as   | a        | determiner     |
|----------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------| 
| sunlight strikes raindrops in the air, they act as a     | prism    | noun           |
|----------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------| 
| strikes raindrops in the air, they act as prism          | and      | conjunction    |
|----------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------| 
| raindrops in the air, they act as a prism and            | form     | verb           |
|----------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------| 
| in the air, they act as a prism and form                 | a        | determiner     |
|----------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------| 
| the air, they act as a prism and form a                  | rainbow. | noun           |
|----------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------| 
| ...                                                      | ...      | ...            | 
|----------------------------------------------------------|----------|----------------|
```

I have the part-of-speech of each word in my training/validation/test set, but I do not want to give the model any part-of-speech information, I want it to infer everything from the raw words (they do go through an encoding in the model structure). However, I do not know how to get the part-of-speech inside the metric calculation function without passing the part-of-speech as part of the data_x or data_y. In other words, right now, my training data is the X column, my labels is the Y column, and I am not passing the part-of-speech column to the model.

Is there any way I can pass the part-of-speech associated with each output sample to the model without using that data in training? for instance, either attaching part-of-speech to X, and then ignoring it in the training, or attaching part-of-speech to Y, and then telling the model not to predict it in the training? Or attach it to neither, and somehow associate it with the data so that it can be seen by the metrics function, but not be used in the model training?

I am using tensorflow 1.15, so I have been using the tf.keras libraries to build my models and metrics.

EDIT 12-20:
I would like to evaluate the accuracy by part-of-speech during the training loop, rather than in a post-processing step. I am looking for how to pass the part-of-speech to the training loop, without using it to train the model. The arguments to `tf.keras.metric.update_weight` are `(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None)` [[link]](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric?version=stable), and I cannot think of how to pass in another argument, like `y_part_of_speech`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to split your data up into parts of speech parcels for evaluation. The training can still be carried out on the full dataset without parts of speech but the evaluation carried out separately for each part of speech.

Assuming you're doing this in Python it could look something like this:

```
# assume we have X_eval, Y_eval, Y_pos 
# these are evaluation features, evaluation truth and evaluation part of speech
# model is your model and score a function that returns the metric given the input 
# feature matrix and ground truth vector

pos_metrics = {}
for pos in Y_pos.unique():
    pos_mask = (Y_pos == pos)
    pos_metrics[pos] = model.score(X_eval[pos_mask], Y_pos[pos_mask])
```

This will give you a dictionary with a metric for each part of speech evaluated separately.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is python, and that makes a ton of sense. So is there a way to do this for the validation set, and evaluate at every epoch? It seems like the equivalent to what you described would be to save a model checkpoint after every epoch and do the equivalent of what you described with X_train/Y_train and X_test/Y_test substituted for Y_eval, but that would be super inefficient for memory, so I would like some way to do this during the training loop.

Comment: Also, should the model.score call actually be `model.score(X_eval[pos_mask], Y_eval[pos_mask])`, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I am not very familiar with tensorflow or deep learning, so not sure about the exact details of how you call the scoring. My `model.score` was just supposed to be a generic scoring operation. You should substitute in however you would normally perform scoring.

Comment: Regarding the scoring at each epoch, is memory really such a problem? If you are able to score the full training set at each epoch, I don't see why you could score each part-of-speech separately?

Comment: I guess memory isn't a problem in this specific case, but I was wondering for the future, when I scale the problem and I'm training on the order of 1000s of epochs (now it's on the order of 10s of epochs). The bigger things is that, ideally, I would like this evaluation to be part of the training loop, not a post processing step, and the way that you suggested would require me to save a checkpoint for every epoch, then load each checkpoint and run the training/test sets through in post-processing, because I cannot pass the part-of-speech into the training loop.

Comment: The more I explain this problem, I realize that it is a TensorFlow specific question. I will edit the post to try to clarify my question. Thanks for the feedback!